# rmarkdown::render problem when called from a package

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've made a small package to reproduce the problem:

```
# example package
devtools::install_github("privefl/minipkg")

# example Rmd
rmd <- system.file("extdata", "Matrix.Rmd", package = "minipkg")
writeLines(readLines(rmd))  ## see content

# works fine
rmarkdown::render(
  rmd,
  "all",
  envir = new.env(),
  encoding = "UTF-8"
)

# !! does not work !!
minipkg::my_render(rmd)
minipkg::my_render  ## see source code
```

I don't understand why the behaviour is different and how to fix this.

**Edit:** I know I can use `Matrix::t()`. My question is more "why do I need to use it in this particular case and not in all the other cases (such as calling `rmarkdown::render()` outside of a package)?".

---

### Error

```
Quitting from lines 10-13 (Matrix.Rmd) 
Error in t.default(mat) : argument is not a matrix
```

### Matrix.Rmd File

````
---
output: html_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(Matrix)
mat <- rsparsematrix(10, 10, 0.1)
t(mat)
```
````

### Console Output:

````
> # example package
> devtools::install_github("privefl/minipkg")
Downloading GitHub repo privefl/minipkg@master
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/md/03gdc4c14z18kbqwpfh4jdfc0000gr/T/RtmpKefs4h/remotes685793b9df4/privefl-minipkg-c02ae62/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘minipkg’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘minipkg_0.1.0.tar.gz’

* installing *source* package ‘minipkg’ ...
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (minipkg)
> # example Rmd
> rmd <- system.file("extdata", "Matrix.Rmd", package = "minipkg")
> writeLines(readLines(rmd))  ## see content
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(Matrix)
mat <- rsparsematrix(10, 10, 0.1)
t(mat)
```

> # works fine
> rmarkdown::render(
+   rmd,
+   "all",
+   envir = new.env(),
+   encoding = "UTF-8"
+ )


processing file: Matrix.Rmd
  |.............                                                    |  20%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........................                                       |  40%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.......................................                          |  60%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................................................             |  80%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: Matrix.knit.md

/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS Matrix.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output Matrix.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /var/folders/md/03gdc4c14z18kbqwpfh4jdfc0000gr/T//RtmpKefs4h/rmarkdown-str68525040df1.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --metadata pagetitle=Matrix.utf8.md 

Output created: Matrix.html
> # !! does not work !!
> minipkg::my_render(rmd)


processing file: Matrix.Rmd
  |.............                                                    |  20%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........................                                       |  40%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.......................................                          |  60%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................................................             |  80%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Quitting from lines 10-13 (Matrix.Rmd) 
Error in t.default(mat) : argument is not a matrix

> minipkg::my_render  ## see source code
function (rmd) 
{
    rmarkdown::render(rmd, "all", envir = new.env(), encoding = "UTF-8")
}
<bytecode: 0x7f89c416c2a8>
<environment: namespace:minipkg>
>
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How it works

The problem is `envir = new.env()`.
What you need is `envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())`:

```
devtools::install_github("privefl/minipkg")
rmd <- system.file("extdata", "Matrix.Rmd", package = "minipkg")

minipkg::my_render(rmd)
# Fails

f <- minipkg::my_render
body(f) <- quote(rmarkdown::render(rmd, "all", envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()), encoding = "UTF-8"))

ns <- getNamespace("minipkg")
unlockBinding("my_render", ns)
assign("my_render", f, envir = ns)

minipkg::my_render(rmd)
# Patched one works :)
```

## Why it works

Look at the default arguments of `new.env()` to find that the default parent environment is `parent.frame()`. Note that from the console, this will be `globalenv()` and from within a package it will be this packages *namespace* (not the same as package environment!).

You can get a package namespace with `getNamespace("pkg")`. It is the environment that contains all (also internal) objects of the package. The problem is that this environment is in a sense "disconnected" from the usual search / method lookup mechanic in R and so you won't find the necessary methods even though they are attached to `search()`.

Now chosing `new.env(parent = globalenv())` sets the parent environment to be on the top of the search path and thus able to find all attached methods.

## Benchmarking different approaches

These three approaches all produce proper html files:

```
#' Render an Rmd file
#' @param rmd Path of the R Markdown file to render.
#' @export
my_render <- function(rmd) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    rmd,
    "all",
    envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()),
    encoding = "UTF-8"
  )
}

#' Render an Rmd file
#' @param rmd Path of the R Markdown file to render.
#' @export
my_render2 <- function(rmd) {
  cl <- parallel::makePSOCKcluster(1)
  on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl), add = TRUE)
  parallel::clusterExport(cl, "rmd", envir = environment())
  parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    rmarkdown::render(rmd, "all", encoding = "UTF-8")
  })[[1]]
}

#' Render an Rmd file
#' @param rmd Path of the R Markdown file to render.
#' @export
my_render3 <- function(rmd) {
    system2(
        command = "R",
        args = c("-e", shQuote(sprintf("rmarkdown::render('%s', 'all', encoding = 'UTF-8')", gsub("\\\\", "/", normalizePath(rmd))))),
        wait = TRUE
    )
}
```

Now it's interesting to compare their speed:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_render("inst/extdata/Matrix.Rmd"), my_render2("inst/extdata/Matrix.Rmd"), my_render3("inst/extdata/Matrix.Rmd"), times = 10L)

[...]

Unit: milliseconds
                                  expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
  my_render("inst/extdata/Matrix.Rmd")  352.7927  410.604  656.5211  460.0608  560.3386 1836.452    10
 my_render2("inst/extdata/Matrix.Rmd") 1981.8844 2015.541 2163.1875 2118.0030 2307.2812 2407.027    10
 my_render3("inst/extdata/Matrix.Rmd") 2061.7076 2079.574 2152.0351 2138.9546 2181.1284 2377.623    10
```

### Conclusions

- `envir = new.env(globalenv())` is by far the fastest (almost 4x faster than the alternatives)
  I expect the overhead to be constant, so it should be irrelevant for larger Rmd files.
- There is no discernible difference between spawning a new proces with `system2` and using a parallel SOCK cluster with 1 node.

Comment: Good job at finding the root of the problem. Yet, it feels wrong to add the global environment to the search path for the Rmd. Does this means that the Rmd has access to the current global env? I was thinking about using `new.env(parent = parent.env(globalenv()))`. But this means that the Rmd has access to packages loaded before, right?

Comment: @F.Privé That might work with already attached packages but new library() calls might modify the search path „above“. Also, source() calls modify globalenv() unless local = TRUE is specified. All in all it‘s probably safer to do system(„RScript -e rmarkdown::render(...)“) and fire up a fresh R session for the knitting. This is essentially what RStudio does when you click Knit.

Comment: I'm not a great fan of system calls inside packages. But using the "same idea" and executing it in a PSOCK cluster, it seems to work fine.

Comment: See `minipkg::my_render2()`.

Comment: @F.Privé That‘s not much different, maybe a bit more overhead for setting up R in slave mode. Anyway, using a parallel package just hides the creation of the R process - still safer than playing with the envir parameter but I think system or system2 are more efficient and clearer as to why. Plus on linux a (default) FORK cluster will have a copy of globalenv(), so care must be taken to specify the cluster type.

Comment: I‘ll look into my_render2() later (on the go atm).

Comment: Did you have time to look at this?

Comment: @F.Privé I did indeed and added a benchmark.
Conclusion: You lose around a factor of 4 for spawning a separate process, but there is no discernible performance difference between your `parallel`approach and `system2`.

Comment: Still, it feels wrong to use the global env as parent env. Anyway, thanks for pointing me to the root of the problem.